# Loopback : Rename file from before remote method using context

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

I want to rename file from before remote hook using context.

```
 container.beforeRemote('upload', function (context, res, next) {
      /////rename file
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can i access files from this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to do it before because we haven't unpacked the multipart form yet.

The `afterRemote` hooks contains enough information to rename the file if you really need to.  Here's an example built on top of loopback's [default storage example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-storage)

```
app.start = function() {
  // Adding an operation hook which renames the recently uploaded file

  var container = app.dataSources.storage.models.container;

  container.afterRemote('upload', (context, res, next) => {

    // The file object is stored in the res param
    let file = res.result.files.file[0];

    // Get the filepath of our datasource, in this case `storage`.
    let root = container.dataSource.settings.root;

    // Get the full path of the file we just uploaded
    // root/containerName/filename.ext
    let filePath = path.resolve(root, file.container, file.name);

    //  aand rename
    fs.rename(filePath, path.resolve(root, file.container, 'newFile.txt'), () => console.log('renamed!'));
  });


  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I want to rename before upload not after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a boot script which will rename the file using a UUID (You need to install UUID package). You can apply other logic such as timestamp etc for renaming the file.

```
var uuid = require('uuid-v4');
module.exports = function(app) {
    var uuid = require('uuid-v4');
    module.exports = function(app) {
        app.dataSources.storage.connector.getFilename = function(origFilename, req, res) {
            var origFilename = origFilename.name;
            var parts = origFilename.split('.'),
                extension = parts[parts.length - 1];
            return uuid() + '.' + extension;
        }
    }
}
```